# How to download mms from the mms broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, mms

I am in the process of creating my own texting app. I have everything but MMS receiving working. I can get the MMS received broadcast, I can create a generic PDU and cast to to a NotificationInd. But then I am lost, how do I translate that into an actual Bitmap image I can then place into an ImageView?

I know I need to use an HTTP connection to download it, I know it involves using APN settings (which I already have, because I can send images).

I have looked at Google's MMS package but that didn't really help much. The most help I have gotten was by decompiling an already working app and looking at the smali.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I need to use HttpConnection to download it, but I don't know what to do after that. So that is where I am stuck right now.

Thanks all.